# Дерево/Лист в c++, установить скрытый столбец

Tags: c++, list, дерево

подскажите как в таблице задать скрытый столбец, в нем будут записываться GUID, и пользователю не зачем его видеть, это необходимо для правильного выбора пользователем строк (checkbox-ов), порядок листа частенько рандомный и вариант "посмотри по нумерации" не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Для потомков, нашел более правильное решение использовать GetItemData/SetItemData, указав некий id в DWORD_PTR